# AIX openSSH allow anyuser any IP (default) but restrict a particular user to an IP

Tags: ssh, aix

Can't seem to come up with the correct Match for this one

sshd should allow anyone from anywhere i.e. the usual/default config, but I want to restrict a user to a IP

For example bob should only be allowed in from IP 1.2.3.4

PS I have added AIX as the O/S. Although PAM is part of AIX it is implemented somewhat differently

Comment: what's wrong with `AllowUsers bob@1.2.3.4` in your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file?

Comment: If I read the manpage correctly that would then only allow bob@1.2.3.4 and no one else

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as nobody else has yet mentioned it, its possible to do this with the `pam_access` module.

You'll need to check the pam stack is invoking this module by looking in `/etc/pam.d/sshd` and adding as an `account` value if it is not there.  IE

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth       required pam_sepermit.so
auth       substack     password-auth
auth       include      postlogin
account    required     pam_nologin.so

account    required     pam_access.so

account    include      password-auth
password   include      password-auth
# pam_selinux.so close should be the first session rule
session    required     pam_selinux.so close
session    required     pam_loginuid.so
# pam_selinux.so open should only be followed by sessions to be executed in the user context
session    required     pam_selinux.so open env_params
session    optional     pam_keyinit.so force revoke
session    include      password-auth
session    include      postlogin
session    required     pam_tty_audit.so enable=*
```

Then, in the access file (default is `/etc/security/access.conf`) add the three following lines (providing no other lines offer any other security setup).

```
+ : bob : 1.2.3.4
- : bob : ALL
+ : ALL : ALL
```

In SSH

I suppose the following would work.

```
<Global scope>
DenyUsers bob

Match Address 1.2.3.4
  AllowUsers bob
```

Comment: My fault - forgot to say AIX

Comment: I added an option that may work in SSH, providing you're not running an ancient version.

Comment: Directive 'AllowUsers' is not allowed within a Match block

Comment: Your running too old a version. My `sshd_config` man page explicitly indicates this is supported.

Answer (score 0):

If you know all other users, this will work:

```
AllowUsers user@ip user2 user3
```

but unfortunately, it's not working with wildcards.

Depending on what your end-goal is, you could force your users to use SSH keys instead of passwords and restrict the host in the users `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file with a `from=` statement (see `man sshd` for infos on the format).

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly, you want to allow all the lucky non-Bob users to come from anywhere, but the hapless Bob can only come from 1.2.3.4.

Maybe try this:

```
AllowUsers !bob
AllowUsers bob@1.2.3.4
```

Comment: This way, alice, charly and their friends can't log in either, or you have to list them separately.

Comment: My understanding of the man page is that !bob is a pattern that matches all users except bob (which includes alice, charly and anyone else). The second line allows bob only from 1.2.3.4.

Comment: It's not working this way.